# Mapping between native std::errc/errno values and some managed exceptions/error codes

Tags: error-handling, .net-core

My .NET-Core app uses a native library that returns standard `errno` codes.
The problem is that these values are not the same on different platforms:
For example, EBADMSG is `104` on Windows and `74` on Linux.
How do I process it uniformly on both platforms? Is there any mapping between POSIX error codes and managed exceptions/error codes?

Comment: Surely that's why you use symbolic names like `EBADMSG ` and not specific numeric values?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, if a native function call gives you some `errno` integer value, you have to somehow map it back to a symbolic name (which is what the question is about).

Answer (score 1):

There is a NuGet package [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/), which implements various native/managed interfaces, and is compatible to both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

You are looking for the function `Mono.Unix.Native.NativeConvert.ToErrno(int)`, which takes a system-specific `errno` integer value and returns the associated symbolic representation as a member of the `Mono.Unix.Native.Errno` enumeration.

There is also the other way round, the function `NativeConvert.FromErrno(Errno)` will convert the given symbolic value into a system-specific integer.

Taking the example from your question:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Mono.Unix.Native.NativeConvert.ToErrno(104).ToString());
```

Output on Windows 10 x64:

```
EBADMSG
```

Output on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x64:

```
ECONNRESET
```